# EXCEL - Get mutiple column headers if row is not blank

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with the table below, there are about 20 columns and 100 rows

|  | Header1 | Header2 | Header3 | Header4 | Header5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name 1 | A | B |  |  | AA |
| Name 2 |  | A |  | C |  |
| Name 3 | B | A | AB |  | A |
| Name 4 |  | C | A | B |  |

I need to get the column headers where cells have value and list them in a seperated sheet, seperated cell. Below is what I want.

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name 1 | Header1 | Header2 | Header5 |  |  |
| Name 2 | Header2 | Header4 |  |  |  |
| Name 3 | Header1 | Header2 | Header3 | Header5 |  |
| Name 4 | Header2 | Header3 | Header4 |  |  |

Is there a function that I can use? VBA is okay too. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With <kbd>Excel 365</kbd> you can try-

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(TRANSPOSE($B$1:$F$1),INDEX(TRANSPOSE($B$2:$F$5),,MATCH(H2,$A$2:$A$5,0))<>0))
```

[image]